# Invoking a Web Service Without using Web Reference with SOAP authencation in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, wse

I need to bind web service reference at run time with SOAP or WSE authentication in ASP.NET.
i can handle this without authentication, but not getting the way to do this with SOAP or WSE authentication.
Any one can help me please...